# How to setup a JQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

So I was trying to set-up a JQuery Datatable as in this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/b8cLVaVlbNKOQhDwI2mw?p=preview

But I keep getting a "No matching records found" pop-up when I try to implement it. How would I be able to fix it?

Here is my JS script:

```
$(function() {
        otable = $('#amdta').dataTable();
        })

        function filterme() {
        //build a regex filter string with an or(|) condition
        var types = $('input:checkbox[name="item"]:checked').map(function() {
            return '^' + this.value + '\$';
        }).get().join('|');
        //filter in column 0, with an regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
        otable.fnFilter(types, 1, true, false, false, false);

        //build a filter string with an or(|) condition
        var frees = $('input:checkbox[name="website"]:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join('|');
        //now filter in column 2, with no regex, no smart filtering, no inputbox,not case sensitive
        otable.fnFilter(frees, 2, false, false, false, false);
```

Here is my HTML

```
<p>
    <label>
        <input onchange="filterme()" type="checkbox" name="website" class="filled-in" value="canadacomputers" />
        <span>Canada Computers</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input onchange="filterme()" type="checkbox" name="item" class="filled-in" value="$2299.0" />
        <span>Item</span>
    </label>
</p>

<input type="text" id="amdin" onkeyup="amdfun()" placeholder="Search for CPU..">

<table id="amdta">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th-sm">Item</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Price</th>
            <th class="th-sm">Website</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    {% for item in items %}
        {% if item.brand == 'amd' %}
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.item }}</td>
                    <td>${{ item.price }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ item.website }}">{{ item.site }}</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: the fiddle works fine for me. check your console for any error

Comment: @AhmedSunny No errors are appearing. I'm assuming by "fiddle" you mean the site "jsfiddle.net", in which case it doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply filtering by a specific price, you do not need to use regular expression, you just apply the filter using the single value.  It might be helpful to add some sample rows with actual values instead of the template and specify exactly what you are trying to filter by each of those check boxes.  Better yet, create a plnkr and provide that link.

Comment: Would it be possible to filter a general term? Let's say my items are all the Ryzen 5 products, would it be possible to set the filter to "Ryzen 5" to get only the Ryzen 5s? Also, I'm not super well versed in Javascript, so would you be able to point out where the regular expression is in my JS script? Here is my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qUnLYH9mh87Q1yq8pL53

Comment: Ok so I managed to make it work, but ideally, I would like it to filter based on a general term, like I described in my previous comment.

Comment: Updated the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/flCyMJDiMpLS2VREEGrs?p=preview). Added two more filters - Ryzen 5 and Ryzen 7 so you can see how it works. The reason why it was not working is two reasons.   You have to update the regex to include zero or more characters before the string termination, '$'. Added a console.log so you can see the regex being built.   You have to use '0' for second arg to fnFilter. It is the column index that you are filtering on. Refer to the datatables [API for fnFilter](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter)